WSL does not have an access to the WiFi hotspot network
I have a running UDP server in the WSL Ubuntu instance.
I need to make it public for the network of the WiFi hotspot on Windows side.
But when I activated the hotspot there is no access to its local ip address from WSL (ping 192.168.137.1 is not responding).
I tried to use the networkingMode=mirrored in the .wslconfig, but the behavior is the same. Hotspot interface is not presented in the ifconfig, only interface with WiFi MAC (for using as client):
$ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:de:80:a3:10:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.199.178.200  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.199.179.255
        ether e8:9c:25:de:62:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7513  bytes 556095 (556.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 448  bytes 44396 (44.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 184  bytes 31013 (31.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 184  bytes 31013 (31.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

loopback0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:15:5d:bd:df:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

my .wslconfig:
[wsl2]
memory=64GB
processors=24
networkingMode=mirrored
dnsTunneling=true
dnsProxy=false
firewall=false
autoProxy=false

[experimental]
hostAddressLoopback=true

How is it possible that I have an interface on Windows and it cannot be pinged from WSL?
Update:
I've tried to install one more repo (Debian), but on WSL 1, and it works - besides eth interfaces the wifi interfaces are appeared and wifi2 is hotspot interface with 192.168.137.1 address.
So, it means that this is the bug of WSL 2.
But for now I cannot change WSL version for my distro and still looking for the workaround for this issue.
